# What are the 2 nfl teams that played each other the least and the most?

Tags: american-football, nfl

What are the 2 nfl teams that played each other the least and the most?
P.S. This is between two teams that exist right now not defunct teams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the end of the 2020 season, all of the current NFC West have played only **4 games** against the **Houston Texans**.

- Seattle Seahawks
- San Francisco 49ers
- Los Angeles Rams
- Arizona Cardinals

That the Texans are involved here is not surprising as they the most recent expansion franchise in the NFL, beginning play in 2002. Unless amended, the rotating schedule of NFL matchups pairs the NFC West with the AFC South in the 2021 season, so the Texans will play all the above teams in the 2021 season.

The record for the most head-to-head matches goes to **Chicago Bears vs. Green Bay Packers** with a stunning **202 games**.

*Stats taken from [here (HOU)](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/htx/head-to-head.htm), [here (CHI)](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/game_query.cgi?tm1=chi&tm2=gnb&yr=all)*

Comment: Mind if I edit in the more direct link (https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/htx/head-to-head.htm) ?

Comment: @Joe go ahead :)  I was just referencing the main page as the results were taken from several pages.

Comment: Also fixed the CHI/GB totals - I think that table must've been a year out of date, as the H2H page shows 202 games.  One other note - it's possible BAL-DET could move into a tie next year, depending on when it's scheduled related to the four games with HOU-NFC West. (They've played 5 times, but will play in this upcoming season assuming nothing happens to the schedule).